# Split string by unicode category

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, unicode, split

I have a string that contains many different characters, and I want to be able to split the string by all the characters that are in the [Po] category in unicode.

How can I easily do this (i.e. I want to avoid enumerating all the characters in this list, and then creating a giant character array, and then splitting by that)? I would also imagine that there are common properties in the way these characters are stored that would make this easier.

So, how can I split a string by all unicode punctuation characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Po` category is [supported by the .NET regular expression engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories), so you can simply do this:

```
Regex.Split("this,is.a!test", @"\p{Po}") // [ "this", "is", "a", "test" ]
```

Comment: Isn't that only punctuation other?

Comment: But what about Ps,Pi,Pf,Pe, etc?

Comment: @soandos you could use `\p{P}`. See the link in my answer "*All punctuation characters. This includes the **Pc**, **Pd**, **Ps**, **Pe**, **Pi**, **Pf**, and **Po** categories*". If you want to include just some of those (e.g. Po and Pc) use a character class, like this: `[\p{Po}\p{Pc}]`.